# Accept/handle print job in C#

Tags: c#, printing, snmp, agent

I'm currently working on an SNMP Simulator, specialized in printer simulation. For now my prototype is working fine. One of the constraints of that project is that it has to be developped in C#.

But there's a feature I'd like to have : accept and handle a print job, to test the monitoring of that part. I can't find any documentation for that, the only things I find are about the monitoring part.

The goal is to be able to act as a printer and let the user chose parameters like "on this page, paper jam" etc… using the MIB.

Do you know any way to do that ?

PS: I know my question is quite vague, sorry :/ but I can't find any information to make it more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything is covered by SNMP. There are only a few standard documents about printing, such as

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1759.txt

which may not focus on every feature a printer supports. As far as I know, there are also vendors' private MIB documents for specific printer models.

If you want to simulate a real world printer, you will have to first check what are the MIB documents a specific model supports, and then try to implement those MIB documents in your simulator.